# Bootstrap Select Plugin Jquery Select Option Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I am using "Bootstrap Select Plugin Jquery". How do I replace it with Select Jquery code.

I would like to choose the value of the example 2.

**Desired result:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GZ6V.png)

**MY Code:**

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').selectpicker();

 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
 
<select class="my-select">
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
  <option value="3">Other</option>
</select>



 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.my-select').selectpicker('val', '2');
```